# Is there a way in Verdaccio to generate package.json files based on what it has in it's storage?

Tags: npm, package, verdaccio

I'm publishing angular packages to Verdaccio to use inside the company. Suddenly, I found out that one of my package is missing, when I run npm install it gives me an error saying Can not find that specific module. When I checked the verdaccio UI it was not there as well then I checked the server where Verdaccio is hosted, there was no package json file inside that package folder but all the .tgz files are there.
[all the tgz files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzLMt.png)

Is there a way to redo all of it's package.json files based on what it has in it's storage?

Verdaccio version -4.0.4

Comment: If there is no package.json inside of the package in the storage, means was removed. The package should be generated automatically anyhow. Could you describe better your environment?

Comment: Yes, There is a possibility that some one deleted it by mistake. For the time being I have published the latest version of that package. Since all the .tgz files are there can I regenerate the package.json. Verdaccio is hosted in a windows server 2012 R2